# Como fazer para que só links do meu domínio abram a minha aplicação?

Tags: android, webview

Se eu clicar em um link relacionado ao meu site, gostaria que, na lista de aplicativos que podem abrir aquele link (Google Chrome, UC Browser e etc), também aparecesse o meu aplicativo, que é um navegador bem simples que funciona usando uma WebView, mas **apenas quando for um link para o meu site**.

Esse é o código do meu aplicativo:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com.br");
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new LinkWebViewClient());
```

Alguém tem pistas de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem de alterar o `intent-filter`, que se encontra no Manisfest.xml, da *activity* que vai responder ao *intent*, para algo deste tipo:

```
<intent-filter>

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:host="oSeuDominio.???" />
    <data android:host="www.oSeuDominio.???" />
    <data android:pathPattern="/.*" />

</intent-filter>
```

Sustitua `oSeuDominio.???` de acordo com o seu domínio.

Comment: Correto, mais tipo: se o link tiver nesse formato: **Meudominio.com/pagina2.html** abre é a index do site. Como ajeita isso para abrir o link solicitado em vez da index?

Comment: É só esse o link que quer abrir?

Comment: Não. É que meu site tem várias páginas... quera assim: qualquer link que conter o meu domínio.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o código que está a utilizar. A minha resposta deveria funcionar para qualquer link do seu domínio, daí estar a usar `<data android:pathPattern="/.*" />`

Comment: creio que deve manipular algo no java para receber o link. Vou da uma pesquisada

Comment: Com o `intent-filter` da resposta o seu aplicativo já aparece na lista nas condições que pretendia?

Comment: sim aparece, só não abre o link que eu cliquei. Abre é a index do site.

Comment: Então a sua pergunta foi respondida. É melhor abrir outra pergunta para esse novo problema. Coloque nela o código que está a usar para obter o link.

Comment: Valeu! Obrigado!

Comment: Veja minha nova pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143280/webview-n%C3%A3o-abre-o-link-solicitado