# WebView não abre o link solicitado

Tags: android

Estava buscando como abrir links relacionado a meu domínio como fiz na minha pergunta anterior e obtive resposta.

> [Como fazer para que só links do meu domínio abram a minha aplicação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143164/como-fazer-para-que-s%C3%B3-links-do-meu-dom%C3%ADnio-abram-a-minha-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o/143204#143204)

Coloquei esse código no AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="http" />
<data android:host="oSeuDominio.???" />
<data android:host="www.oSeuDominio.???" />
<data android:pathPattern="/.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Tipo quando clico em um link relacionado ao meu site, por exemplo no WhatsApp e meu aparece na lista que pode abrir aquele link.

> O problema é que, quando clico o App que é um **navegador simples** que funciona com WebView, não abre  o link que foi clicado e sim a página inicial(index.php) do site.

Meu código Java:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (isOnline()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Carregando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://xxxx.xxx");
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new LinkWebViewClient());
        mWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
   }
   else
    [...]
    }
    private class LinkWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    {
        if(isOnline()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            webview.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sem conexão", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.conexaofail);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{

    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
    {
        if (isOnline()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.conexaofail);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Nesta linha `mWebView.loadUrl("http://xxxx.xxx");` você tem o link para o seu site?

Comment: Isso mesmo, é ai! Tipo quando abro o App ele carrega primeiro essa url ai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem de obter o *url* do link que foi clicado.

Essa informação é passada no *Intent* que lançou a sua aplicação.
Se a *Action* desse *Intent* for *Intent.ACTION_VIEW* então a *url* pode ser obtida através do método `getData()`.

No método `onCreate()`:

```
......
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://xxxx.xxx");//Link por defeito

Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_VIEW){
    uri = intent.getData()
}
.....
.....
mWebView.loadUrl(uri.toString());
.....
```

Comment: Um problema: o codigo **mWebView.loadUrl(uri.toString);** esse **toString** ficou vermelho, e o erro é: Cannot resolve to symbol "toString"

Comment: `toString` é um método falta acrescentar 2 parêntesis: `toString()`

Comment: Nossa cara!  Deu certinho e nem sei como ti agradecer!

Comment: Votando e aceitando as respostas que te são úteis:)

Comment: Sem querer ser explorador, se eu fizer  mais uma pergunta que creio que seja simples pra você que é experiente no assunto. Você responde?

Comment: Você pode fazer todas as perguntas que quiser, se eu souber responderei(eu ou outro). Só será considerado "explorador" se pedir "código pronto", não mostrando esforço da sua parte para tentar resolver.

Comment: Está aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143298/abrir-links-externos-em-outro-navegador se poder  me ajudar ficarei grato