# Abrir links externos em outro navegador

Tags: java, android

Então eu tenho um App que é meu site todo responsivo e está funcionando perfeitamente.

Mas eu gostaria de que os links externos sejam aberto em outro navegador. Por exemplo: O usuário clica em um anúncio do Google adsense  que tem pelo o site e o site do anúncio abre no mesmo App e gostaria que fosse para outro, sendo assim, qualquer link diferente do meu domínio seja solicitado que abra em outro navegador.

```
Meu código Java:

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (isOnline()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Carregando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://xxxx.xx");//Link por defeito
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_VIEW){
            uri = intent.getData();
        }
        mWebView.loadUrl(uri.toString());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new LinkWebViewClient());
        mWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
   }
   else
    [...]
    }
    private class LinkWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    {
        if(isOnline()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            webview.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sem conexão", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.conexaofail);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{

    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
    {
        if (isOnline()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.conexaofail);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se haverá outra solução melhor mas, assim de repente, é esta a que me ocorre.

Pode utilizar o método `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` para interceptar a *url* e verificar se é externa ao seu domínio e, se sim, lançar um *browser*

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

    if(isOnline()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(uri.getHost().equals("exemplo.com"){//Substitua pelo seu domínio
            //webview.loadUrl(url);//Está a mais
            return false;
        }
        else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sem conexão", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.conexaofail);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Vou fazer um teste.

Comment: Desculpa minha ignorancia, como  informei: sou inexperiente em java... então o esquema ai que você fez dentro do if **uri** está vermelho e com a mensagem **Cannot resolve to symbol  "uri"**.

Comment: acho resolvi com isso: **Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);**  vou testar! Aguarde

Comment: Até que resolveu sua resposta! Só que além de aparecer os navegadores  o site ainda abre no App. Mais vou considerar sua resposta, ajudou muito. Vou tentar resolver isso aqui. Obrigado!

Comment: Veja as alterações, agora um link externo já não deve abrir na *WebView*. Tenha em atenção aos *returns* e a chamada a `webview.loadUrl(url)` está a mais,

Comment: Tudo certo! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Ramaral, pode me responder essa questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151060/navegador-n%C3%A3o-recarrega-a-%C3%BAltima-p%C3%A1gina