# Navegador não recarrega a última página

Tags: java, android

Meu aplicativo é um simples navegador web exclusivo para meu site, porém estou enfrentando um "problema" que está irritando.

É o seguinte, estou usando de boa o aplicativo ai eu deixo em segundo plano e abro outro navegador por exemplo o google chrome ou qualquer outro aplicativo que consome muita memória e meu aplicativo em segundo plano ele para.
Quando volto pra ele, a página recarrega MAS EM VEZ DE RECARREGAR A ÚLTIMA PÁGINA QUE FOI ACESSADA, ele recarrega é a do link principal do site ou seja a index.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if (isOnline()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Carregando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://xxxx.xx");//Link por defeito
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_VIEW){
        uri = intent.getData();
    }
    mWebView.loadUrl(uri.toString());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new LinkWebViewClient());
    mWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    }
else
[...]
}
private class LinkWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
{
    if(isOnline()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sem conexão", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.conexaofail);
        return false;
    }
}
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {

if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
{
    if (isOnline()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.conexaofail);
        return false;
    }
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

Como faço com esse código acima para que possa recarregar a última página?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guarde o *URL* da página que estava a ser visualizada na altura em que a aplicação passou para segundo plano.
Pode usar a *SharedPreferences* para isso.

Escreva dois métodos, um para guardar e outro para ler:

```
private void saveUrl(String url){
    SharedPreferences preferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    preferences.edit().putString("Url",url).apply();
}

private String readUrl(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return preferences.getString("Url","http://xxxx.xx");// se não houver nenhum guardado usa o Link por defeito
}
```

Utilize o método `onStop()` da *Activity* para guardar o *URL*

```
@override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    String url = mWebView.getUrl();
    saveUrl(url);
}
```

No método `onCreate()`, lei-a o *URL* guardado e use-o na *WebView*:

```
if (isOnline()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Carregando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    String url = readUrl();//Lê o url guardado
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);//usa o url 

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_VIEW){
        uri = intent.getData();
    }
    mWebView.loadUrl(uri.toString());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new LinkWebViewClient());
    mWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    }
else{
.....
.....
```

Se quiser que, quando a aplicação for abandonada pelo usuário por meio da *"Back Key"*, a aplicação arranque na página *default*, altere o método `onStop()` assim:

```
@override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    if(isFinishing()){
        saveUrl("http://xxxx.xx");
    }else{
        String url = mWebView.getUrl();
        saveUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ramaral funcionou, só pra lembrar que tem um erro no seu código: **preferences.edit.putString("Url",url).apply();** onde alterei para **preferences.edit().putString("Url",url).apply();**. Aproveitando: Não há nenhuma maneira de impedir que o aplicativo pare de funcionar em segundo plano? e muito obrigado por me ajudar!

Comment: Eita, um problema: Quando fecho o aplicativo e abro de novo ele abre na ultima URL. Não tem como apagar a URL salva caso fecha o aplicativo? Queria isso apenas se ele travasse em segundo plano.

Comment: O que você entende por "fechar o aplicativo"? O Android não tem esse conceito. Repare que o próprio browser padrão do Android tem esse comportamento. Não, não há forma de evitar que a aplicação seja destruída caso o Android necessite de memória.

Comment: Faça o override do método onDestroy(): `protected void onDestroy(){ super.onDestroy(); saveUrl("http://xxxx.xx");}` e reze para que ele não seja chamado quando a Android destruir a aplicação, por falta de memória.

Comment: Ok, irei testar! Obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: Olá @ramaral, poderia me explicar um pouco sobre esse "onBackPressed()"? tipo coloquei aqui na minha aplicação e cliquei no botão "voltar" até sair dp App mais não salvou a URL no saveUrl(). Pode me ajudar?

Comment: O método `onBackPressed()` é chamado quando o usuário clica no botão "voltar". Julgo que o que está a acontecer é que o método `onStop()` ao ser chamado antes de a aplicação finalizar grava o URL que está na webview.

Comment: Editei a resposta. Em vez de usar `onBackPressed()` verifico no `onStop()` se a app está a ser fechada.

Comment: Funcionou conforme o esperado! Muito obrigado!

Comment: me ajuda com essa questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169537/posicionar-bot%C3%A3o-em-cima-do-do-an%C3%BAncio