# Posicionar botão em cima do do anúncio

Tags: android, xml, admob

Olá, gostaria de saber como coloco um botão de fechar anúncio no canto da tela, em cima do anúncio.

Até tentei aqui mais pega espaço da webview acima e não fica transparente a parte, por exemplo: *O botão fica no canto mais toma espaço da webview e o fundo não fica transparente.*

Veja o exemplo:
[image: Como eu quero]
**Veja que no X tem na esquerda todo azul, não queria isso, apenas o X ali onde está mesmo, mas sem essa parte azul.**

Código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adsContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.xxxxxxxxxx.android.MainActivity"
android:padding="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="#2c3e50">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:indeterminate="false" />
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameAds"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation=“vertical”>
<Button
        android:id="@+id/closeAd"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        ads:backgroundTint="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
        android:visibility="visible" />
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ID_ANUNCIO_BANNER"/>          
    </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Não está claro o que pretende. Se possível coloque uma imagem de como está e outra de como quer que apareça.

Comment: Coloquei uma imagem de exemplo. Espero que você entenda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative layout pra agrupar o bottom de fechar e o anúncio. 
Quando o usuário clicar em fechar tu muda o relative layout pra visibilidade GONE.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adsContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.xxxxxxxxxx.android.MainActivity"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#2c3e50">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:indeterminate="false" />
        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameAds"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation=“vertical”>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/closeAd"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            ads:backgroundTint="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/ID_ANUNCIO_BANNER"/>          
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela a resposta! Mas não consigo entender assim, ainda sou novato na área de Android!

Comment: Esqueci de vir aqui a tarde! Amanhã vou testar e posto o resultado! Obrigado!

Comment: Ajustei a resposta com base na imagem que voce postou.

Comment: Corrigir um erro e editei sua resposta! Muito obrigado!