# webview dentro do Fragnent Quero abrir meu site dentro do webview, e os links dentro site devem abrir fora

Tags: android, mobile, webview

REFORÇO QUE ESTOU ABRINDO WEBVIEW EM UM FRAGMENT E NÃO NO MAIN ACTIVITY 
- Quero abrir meu site dentro do webview, e os links de outros sites devem abrir fora, no navegador do celular normal, porem isso não ocorre. Meu webview está dentro de um fragment. Podem me ajudar?

MEU CÓDIGO :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_principal, container, false);
    WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);

    //se eu desabilito essa linha resolve, porem tudo abre fora do app, e 
    //queria somente que os links listados no site abrissem fora.

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://meusite.com/");

    return v;

}

    public class WebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {


        private PrincipalFragment activity = null;
        public WebViewClientImpl(PrincipalFragment activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
            if(url.contains("https://meusite.com")) return false;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            activity.startActivity(intent);

            return true;

        }

    }
```

**Fragmente_principal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tentei e não resolve, estou abrindo o webview dentro de um fragment! Se tiver alguma sugestão interesso!

Comment: Algum erro? Tem certeza que colocou as classe dentro dos lugares corretos? Colocou um Log.i() dentro do shouldOverrideUrlLoading para ter certeza que o método é chamado? Sabe fazer um debug simples com Log.i, Log.d, etc? Sabe usar break-point? Pode dar mais detalhes? Se conseguir notar o problema edite a pergunta e seja bem claro em onde falhou.

Comment: o problema é que não ocorre erros, eu só queria que meu dominio.com.br ficasse dentro do webview, e os links dentro do site abrissem fora do webview, quando faço isso fora do fragment funciona... eu estou com dúvida de onde colocar o método , pois como disse o startActivity(i); dá erro as soluções são : add  qualifier activity to method
Creat Method StartActivity
e import static method  ...

Comment: Eu tenho uma classe public class WebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient , é dentro dela que vou colocar a solução que me informou correto?
o método já criei nessa classe e na classe PrincipalFragment... porém sem sucesso

Comment: public class WebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {


    private PrincipalFragment activity = null;
    public WebViewClientImpl(PrincipalFragment activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        if(url.contains("meu.com")) return false;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        activity.startActivity(intent);

        return true;

    }

}

Comment: Tenta interceptar os links e trata eles pra abrir com um navegador

Comment: PrincipalFragment *não deixa usar @
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, a*Nullable ViewGroup container, a*Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_principal, container, false);
        WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);

       
        //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://meu.com/");

        return v;

Comment: @MurilloComino como faço isso amigo? Nunca pensei nisso!

Comment: Posta o codigo na pergunta e náo nos comentarios, posta tudo (removendo dados como senhas e endereços de apis) porque só com isto não dá para ter certeza.

Comment: Ok, vou fazer isso

Comment: Atualizei olha se ajuda, coloquei o meu código original, já tentei vários métodos aqui do stack, porém ou abre tudo dentro do meu fragment ou abre tudo fora ...
Quero agradecer a todos pela atenção até o momento!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não seria o caso de ter um if no PrincipalFragmente que verifique se a URL é a mesma do meu site e caso não seja abrir fora??
Só não consegui aqui estruturar isso...

Comment: @JúniorAlencar não sei como esta o seu código de fato, você pode ter uns 20 fragments, subfragments, intents, etc. Pode ser qualquer coisa ai que falhou, eu uso basicamente o mesmo código, links da empresa abrem no webview, links de outros sites abrem no navegador principal do usuario. É provavel que você esteja fazendo alguma confusão. Chegou a colocar um Log dentro de `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` pra ver se esta funcionando?

Comment: Não sei colocar Log amigo, pode me explicar?

Comment: Bom eu só queria uma ajuda, meu código esta assim e como expliquei ocorre isso, se preferir posso te enviar o código ou o app se quiser ver.
Desde Já grato pela prontidão em ajudar! 
Peço desculpas por não ser tão claro...

Comment: Somente abre fora mas ai abre todos os links quando eu comento essa linha =  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Sem comentar tudo abre dentro do app. 
Quando faço em uma Activity normal sem ser Fragmente, funciona normal, porem dessa forma inutiliza os nav_ do meu menu  que é algo que não posso alterar.

Comment: Junior teu código simplesmente está diferente do que eu sugeri no começo, faça exatamente como este: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143300/3635 e troque `if(uri.getHost().equals("exemplo.com"){` e troque por `if(uri.getHost().equals("meusite.com"){`, é apenas o endereço do site, sem arquivo, pastas ou barras, só algo como `www.meusite.com`, sem mais nada.

Comment: @Guilherme, ja tentei usar esse, o problema é que está dando err nesse isOnline, no getApplicationContext, startActivity, setContentView, e no conexaofail , e todas as importações ou alterações que android studio sugere não resolve, pois ele cria metodos que não fazem o app rodar e sim gera outros erros tipo o isOnline ele gera um metodo ou um getter que geram outro erro... e qualquer tratativa que tendo fazer o app nem abre...

Comment: Se puder me explicar pra que serve essas variáveis, pois no meu app elas aparecem como não utilizadas  e deve ser por isso que ocorre o erro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo o jeito que você implementou o webview, ao invés de:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

o certo é instanciar a classe que você criou que estenda WebViewClient, então seria:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
```

O restante do seu fragment mantém.

Na Classe WebViewClientImpl deixe o método override desse jeito:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
    if(url.contains("https://meusite.com")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        //Use o método a seguir caso, o seu webview continua carregando
        //as páginas que o browser deveria abrir (diferente do seu host) 
        webView.stopLoading();

        return false;
    }

}
```

Ou você pode deixar esse método override do jeito que o Guilherme Nascimento sugeriu:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {

     Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

    if(uri.getHost().equals("meusite.com")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        //Use o método a seguir caso, o seu webview continua carregando
        //as páginas que o browser deveria abrir (diferente do seu host) 
        webView.stopLoading();

        return false;
    }

}
```

Espero ter ajudado. E lembre-se de trocar as urls.

Comment: Fala @Murilo,  Nossa irmão agora sim, esta abrindo o link que deveria ser fora está abrindo no navegador, único detalhe é que os links do meu site agora não carregam nem dentro do webview nem fora, testei com seu código e com o do Guilherme e se coloco seu código sem alterar o webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); ai volta a abir tudo fora... nossa devem estar com raiva de mim, o estranho é que se uma coisa funciona a outra não... mas  webView.stopLoading(); eu nem imaginei isso, único detalhe agora é que os links do meu site não abrem, os demais estão abrindo fora perfeitamente .

Comment: Consegui resolver amigo, fiz o seguinte: usei seu código que salvou minha vida, e acrescentei a seguinte linha : webView.loadUrl(url);
Ficou assim o código:

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        if(url.contains("meusite.com/")) {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

Restante do código ficou igual ao que me passou!
Muito obrigado a todos de coração pela ajuda! 
Como posso agradecer vocês?

Comment: eu edito aqui no responder a pergunta? nunca usei essa rede social, mas estou tão feliz que preciso de alguma forma agradecer vocês!!!

Comment: @JúniorAlencar que bom que resolveu, mas se você já está chamando a url fora, não precisaria chamar dentro de novo. Pra marcar minha resposta é só ir no top dela do lado esquerdo e marcar como respondida e/ou como útil.

Comment: Pois eh, mas foi forma que funcionou 100%. Talvez seja versão do meu Android, 3.0.1. de toda forma estou grato de mais!!!